# Добавление/удаление класса к элементу

Tags: javascript, html

Есть несколько строк в таблице с такой структурой:

```
<div class="trading__market-table-row" id="CoinProd_1" name="CoinID_1" onclick='ChangeCoinProdBuySell("CoinID_1");'>
                                <div class="trading__star-wrapper">
                                <div class="trading__star" id="star">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="trading__market-table-wrap">
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-circle trading__market-table-circle--green" name="Point_1" onclick='ChangeColorGreenPoint("Point_1");'></div>
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-coin">1</div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="trading__market-table-price"></div>
                                    <div class="trading__market-table-volume"  ></div>
                                    <div class="trading__market-table-change"  ></div>
                                </div>
```

При выделении какой-то строки срабатывает js код, который добавляет класс к классу `class="trading__market-table-row"` и подсвечивает выбранную строку и удаляет класс, когда выделена друга строка

```
for (var i = 0; i < MarcetTableRow.length; i++) {
                        MarcetTableRow[i].classList.remove('trading__market-table-row-active');

                    }
                    var Coin_Elements = document.getElementsByName(NameCoinProd);
                    for (var i = 0; i < Coin_Elements.length; i++) {
                        Coin_Elements[i].classList.add('trading__market-table-row-active');




                    }
```

Как мне при выделении добавить еще 1 класс( иудалять его соответственно) но к конкретному классу, в моем случае к `<div class="trading__star">` Т.е в итоге должно получиться `<div class="trading__star active">`
Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < MarcetTableRow.length; i++) {
    MarcetTableRow[i].classList.remove('trading__market-table-row-active');
    MarcetTableRow[i].querySelector('.trading__star').classList.remove('active');
}
var Coin_Elements = document.getElementsByName(NameCoinProd);
for (var i = 0; i < Coin_Elements.length; i++) {
    Coin_Elements[i].classList.add('trading__market-table-row-active');
    Coin_Elements[i].querySelector('.trading__star').classList.add('active');
}
```